# Replace rule with function? Derivatives don't evaluate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

Say I have an expression (call it expr) involving a function, `f[x]`. I'd like to be able to evaluate that for a particular choice of `f[x]` without setting that choice for the whole session. I thought to do this using a replacement,

```
expr /. f[x_]->x^2
```

(where `expr` is some expression involving `f[x]` and I want to set `f` to `x^2`), but this doesn't work on derivatives, e.g., if `expr` contains `f'[x]` then it will stay as `f'[x]` rather than become `2x`.

What's the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Check `FullForm[f'[x]]` to understand why, and figure out the appropriate replacement rule.

Comment: István - alright, I can see why it doesn't work, although I'm not sure how to construct a more general replacement rule. Still learning. Any hints?

Comment: You can replace `f` by a pure function if you want things like derivatives to work. `f->Function[x, x^2]`

Comment: That's perfect!! That's the sort of simple solution I was hoping existed. If you write it as an answer I'll happily check it.

If you or someone else wouldn't mind explaining, is there a reason to prefer either this solution or your Block solution?

Comment: Adam you should ping with a @ the user you talk to. I hadn't seen this last comment of yours. Both work in this case, but the `Block` solution is slightly more general, and is the general solution for what you explicitly asked for: "evaluate something for a particular choice of some symbol without it affecting the whole session"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `Block` seems more appropriate

```
Block[{f}, f[x_]:=x^2;
expr]
```

Answer (score 13):

Some different solutions to have this topic as a generic one:

```
expr = D[f[x y], x] + f[x, y]

expr /. f -> (#^2 &)
```

> ```
> 2 x + x^2
> ```

or more verbose:

```
expr /. f -> Function[x, x^2]
```

> ```
> 2 x + x^2
> ```

This functionality is also included in my `dChange` implementation from [Analogue for Maple's dchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80241/5478):

```
dChange[
   expr,
   f[x, y] == x^2
]
```

Comment: Thank you, this a nice solution!