# Evaluation of Derivative in a Module

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation

Can someone help me understand the evaluation procedure in the following two pieces of code?

```
test[] := Module[{expression},
  Clear[F];
  expression = Derivative[0,1][F][x,y];
  F[x_,y_] = y-x^2+1;
  Return[expression];
];

test[func_] := Module[{expression},
  Clear[F];
  expression = Derivative[0,1][F][x,y];
  F[x_,y_] = func;
  Return[expression];
];

test[]
test[y - x^2 + 1]
```

> 1
>
> 0

I expected the output to be 1 in the second case.

I believe the major issue (which we can identify using `Trace`) is that when `test` is called without an argument, `F` is assigned as expected:

```
F[x_,y_]=y-x^2+1;
```

However, when `test` is called with an argument, `F` receives a different assignment using locally defined variables:

```
F[x$_,y$_]=y-x^2+1;
```

If I can figure out how to have `F` assigned as in the former, then I believe my issue will be resolved and the outputs will match.

**Context**: I know there is an easier way to compute a partial derivative with respect to a variable, however that is not my ultimate goal. In the end, `expression` will be much more complex and involve mixed partial derivatives of F. I want *Mathematica* to replace all the instances of these `Derivative`s. I do not think I can use a `ReplaceAll` since I am not sure what `Derivative`s will actually show up.

Comment: First by `(F^(0,1))[x,y]`, do you mean `D[F[x,y],y]` ? And second, what happens if you put the definition (`F[x_,y_]`) before the evaluation of `expression`?  I think that will work !

Comment: 1) Yes, I just fixed the code/output. 2) Moving the function definition does not seem to change the output.

Comment: Can you use derivative in this way `expression := D[F[x, y], y]` for the second one?

Comment: No, in my case `expression` will involve `Derivative` and not `D`.

Comment: Jens' answer is the one to use; however, there is another workaround: `F[u_, v_] = func /. {x -> u, y -> v}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cleaning up your syntax (which involves a non-localized varable `F` and an unnecessary `Return`) the second case coud be written like this:

```
test[func_] := Module[
  {expression, f},
  expression = Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y];
  f = Function[{x, y}, #] &[func];
  expression]
```

Then the expected result comes out:

```
test[y - x^2 + 1]

(* ==> 1 *)
```

What I did here is to define `f` as a `Function` because that's the only way you can substitute it into `expression` when it's defined with `Derivative`. The difference between `Derivative` and `D` is that the former does derivatives on the function slots without any reference to the names of the variables that go into those slots, and then substitutes the variables into the resulting derivative *afterwards*. By contrast, `D` uses the variable names as a way to identify what the correct "slots" of the expression are in the first place.

So therefore, `Derivative` needs a `Function` to operate on. Since `func` is an *expression* and not a function, we have to create a function ourselves. But that leaves the final step: `Function` has attribute `HoldAll`, so I cannot put the dummy argument `func` into the body of `Function` before it gets evaluated. This is circumvented by leaving the body open with `#` and applying that "empty" `Function` as a function to the dummy argument at the time you call `test`.

Comment: Perfect, that makes a lot of sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Get here from [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40190/11867), since codes like `test[func_] := 
 Module[{expression, f}, f[x_, y_] = func; 
  expression = Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y];
  expression]` not working. I do not quite understand what is happening here, would you please give me a hint?