# Substituting inside a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, replacement

```
x y''[x]+2y'[x]+l^2 x y[x]==0/.y[x]->Cos[x]
```

I think above code shows what I want to do quite clearly. How do I make it happen. Only y[x] is replaced.

Comment: Try `y -> Cos`.

Comment: For more general usage you can use `dChange` like: `dChange[
 x y''[x] + 2 y'[x] + l^2 x y[x] == 0,
 y[x] == Cos[x]
 ]`. [80241](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80241/5478) - feedback appreciated.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. what if I wanted to change it into Cos^2 ?

Comment: Then you do `y -> Function[x, Cos[x]^2]`…

Comment: thanks, make that into an answer so that the question doesnt remain unanswered

Comment: I'd prefer that you answer your question yourself. Maybe, you can even talk about `Function[]` and `y -> Cos[#]^2 &` in the answer you'll write…

Comment: This is the first time I had seen that so I'll look into that more.

Comment: @grdgfgr Take a look at links in the topic I've provided above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has been asked for times, 
[Evaluation of Derivative in a Module](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80702/evaluation-of-derivative-in-a-module/) and [Replace rule with function? Derivatives don't evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40189/replace-rule-with-function-derivatives-dont-evaluate/).

Here are several ways to solve it:

If you do not mind pollute `Global` namespace, assign the function first.

```
y[x_] = Cos[x]
x y''[x] + 2 y'[x] + l^2 x y[x] == 0
```

If you mind, assign it in a `Block`

```
Block[{y}, y[x_] = Cos[x];   
x y''[x] + 2 y'[x] + l^2 x y[x] == 0]
```

or, replace it by a pure function:

```
x y''[x] + 2 y'[x] + l^2 x y[x] == 0 /. y -> Function[x, Cos[x]]
```

If you are trying to do something more complex, then these methods will fail:

```
In[1]:= F[func_] := Block[{y}, y[x_] = func;
  x y''[x] + 2 y'[x] + l^2 x y[x] == 0]

In[2]:= F[Cos[x]]

Out[2]= l^2 x Cos[x] == 0
```

and

```
In[1]:= F[func_] := x y''[x] + 2 y'[x] + l^2 x y[x] == 0 /. y -> Function[x, func]

In[2]:= F[Cos[x]]

Out[2]= l^2 x Cos[x] == 0
```

The methods in the link will work:

```
In[7]:= F[func_] := 
 Block[{y, e}, e = x y''[x] + 2 y'[x] + l^2 x y[x] == 0;
    e /. y -> Function[x, #]] &[func]

In[8]:= F[Cos[x]]

Out[8]= -x Cos[x] + l^2 x Cos[x] - 2 Sin[x] == 0
```

or

```
In[11]:= F[func_] := 
 x y''[x] + 2 y'[x] + l^2 x y[x] == 0 /. y -> Function[x, #] &[func]

In[12]:= F[Cos[x]]

Out[12]= -x Cos[x] + l^2 x Cos[x] - 2 Sin[x] == 0
```

I do not quite understand why the last two methods work, I hope someone can explain it in this answer.